# Magento 1.X and MasterCard 2-Series BIN. Will it work?

Tags: magento-1.7

As some of you may be aware MasterCard is launching 2 Series BIN, and there are steps required for merchants to be compliant.
More on this topic:
https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/issuers/get-support/2-series-bin-expansion.html

Is Magento 1.x compliant with such changes?